# Integromat-Airtable integration: Create record with synced linked record -- record id not found

Tags: airtable, make.com

I've created a scenario where a customer submits an order form jotform. In airtable, I have an "Order Line Item" table in my "Sales" base that links to a record from the "Inventory" table from the "Inventory" base. This linked record column is called "Inventory ID". It also has a linked record to my "Order" table in the "Sales" base.

--order line item table--
[image]

In integromat, I have a "Create Record" airbase tool. When I manually put in the Order ID, that creates the new order line item record no problem. But when I manually put in the Inventory ID record, it says it doesn't exist. And, I've tried both the POST API and the Create Record tool.

--synced inventory table--
[image]

--integromat scenario excerpt--

[image]

Is this a bug in the airtable API? I will reach out to airtable community forum as well to see if they have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Someone in the integromat facebook community ...

FB Person:
As I understand how airtable record ID works, synced inventory ID (from another base) is different from that base's recordID.
try to create a recordID formula field and use that instead as reference?

Wichie Artu:
You're a godsend!
The Inventory ID in the Sales base is DIFFERENT from the Inventory ID in the Inventory base. I did a formula in the Sales base to get that record id, and used that.
[image]